# How can WSO2 pick up messages from ActiveMQ without calling any WSO2 api or proxy by client application?

Tags: wso2, activemq-classic

How can WSO2 pick up messages from ActiveMQ without calling any WSO2 api or proxy by client application?

[Please note:- Source System will send messages through ActiveMQ and WSO2 will have to pick up those messages]

Can anybody provide any solution?? I am clueless...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to:

1. Configure wso2 esb to work with activemq...copy /lib
   directory to < ESB_HOME>/repository/components/lib
2. Enable and configure JMSReceiver and JMSSender for Activemq in conf/axis2/axis2.xml. uncomment the configuration for activemq.
3. The wso2 esb proxy need jms transport active inside it configuration.
4. configure this parameters after target section inside proxy configuration:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="ForwardProxy" startOnLoad="true" statistics="disable" trace="disable" transports="jms1">
    <target>
    </target>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.DestinationType">queue</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.Destination">yourQueue</parameter>
    <parameter name="transport.jms.ContentType">
        <rules xmlns="">
           <jmsProperty>contentType</jmsProperty>
           <default>application/xml</default>
        </rules>
    </parameter>
<parametername="transport.jms.ConnectionFactory">
  myQueueConnectionFactory
</parameter>
    </proxy>
```

5. create yourQueue inside activeMQ.
6. put a message in yourQueue.